# what can i get over HDMI for this TV?

Tags: video, television, hdmi, hdr, edid

Panasonic TX-65GXR900

here's its EDID:

```
00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 34 a9 96 a2 01 01 01 01 
00 1d 01 03 80 80 48 78 0a da ff a3 58 4a a2 29 
17 49 4b 20 08 00 31 40 61 40 01 01 01 01 01 01 
01 01 01 01 01 01 08 e8 00 30 f2 70 5a 80 b0 58 
8a 00 ba 88 21 00 00 1e 02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40 
58 2c 45 00 ba 88 21 00 00 1e 00 00 00 fc 00 50 
61 6e 61 73 6f 6e 69 63 2d 54 56 0a 00 00 00 fd 
00 17 3d 0f 88 3c 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 01 1d 

02 03 6c f0 57 61 60 10 1f 66 65 05 14 20 21 22 
04 13 03 12 07 16 5d 5e 5f 62 63 64 2c 0d 07 01 
15 07 50 57 07 01 67 04 03 83 0f 00 00 6e 03 0c 
00 10 00 38 3c 2f 08 80 01 02 03 04 68 d8 5d c4 
01 78 80 03 02 e2 00 4b e3 05 ff 01 e2 0f 33 e3 
06 0f 01 e5 01 8b 84 90 01 eb 01 46 d0 00 44 73 
58 86 44 5f 7e e6 11 46 d0 00 70 00 66 21 56 aa 
51 00 1e 30 46 8f 33 00 ba 88 21 00 00 1e 00 bc
```

judging from what `edid-decode` says, it seems to me that this HDMI input only supports 30 FPS 12-bit 4:2:0. am i interpreting the data correctly? and i'm not sure about HDR10+. does it support it?

looks like HDMI capabilities of my TV are limited, but i guess it will accurately display files with the following video streams, if played with a proper media player on a proper video card and transmitted through a proper cable:

a live show:

```
bitrate: 60748 kb/s
Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
```

a movie:

```
bitrate: 73847 kb/s
Video: hevc (Main 10) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc
```

if yes, then what video card should i buy for that? i'd like it also to be silent, so maybe a mobile or embedded APU can handle that?

Answer (score 0):

One should use modern version of edid-decode to decode this complex edid. https://git.linuxtv.org/edid-decode.git

If you were to use it:

```
Block 0, Base EDID:
  EDID Structure Version & Revision: 1.3
  Vendor & Product Identification:
    Manufacturer: MEI
    Model: 41622
    Serial Number: 16843009
    Made in: 2019
  Basic Display Parameters & Features:
    Digital display
    Maximum image size: 128 cm x 72 cm
    Gamma: 2.20
    RGB color display
    First detailed timing is the preferred timing
  Color Characteristics:
    Red  : 0.6396, 0.3447
    Green: 0.2910, 0.6347
    Blue : 0.1630, 0.0927
    White: 0.2880, 0.2958
  Established Timings I & II:
    DMT 0x04:   640x480    59.940 Hz   4:3    31.469 kHz   25.175 MHz
    DMT 0x10:  1024x768    60.004 Hz   4:3    48.363 kHz   65.000 MHz
  Standard Timings:
    DMT 0x04:   640x480    59.940 Hz   4:3    31.469 kHz   25.175 MHz
    DMT 0x10:  1024x768    60.004 Hz   4:3    48.363 kHz   65.000 MHz
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 1:  3840x2160   60.000 Hz  16:9   135.000 kHz  594.000 MHz (698 mm x 392 mm)
                 Hfront  176 Hsync  88 Hback 296 Hpol P
                 Vfront    8 Vsync  10 Vback  72 Vpol P
    DTD 2:  1920x1080   60.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz  148.500 MHz (698 mm x 392 mm)
                 Hfront   88 Hsync  44 Hback 148 Hpol P
                 Vfront    4 Vsync   5 Vback  36 Vpol P
    Display Product Name: 'Panasonic-TV'
  Display Range Limits:
    Monitor ranges (GTF): 23-61 Hz V, 15-136 kHz H, max dotclock 600 MHz
  Extension blocks: 1
Checksum: 0x1d

----------------

Block 1, CTA-861 Extension Block:
  Revision: 3
  Underscans IT Video Formats by default
  Basic audio support
  Supports YCbCr 4:4:4
  Supports YCbCr 4:2:2
  Native detailed modes: 0
  Video Data Block:
    VIC  97:  3840x2160   60.000 Hz  16:9   135.000 kHz  594.000 MHz
    VIC  96:  3840x2160   50.000 Hz  16:9   112.500 kHz  594.000 MHz
    VIC  16:  1920x1080   60.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz  148.500 MHz
    VIC  31:  1920x1080   50.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz  148.500 MHz
    VIC 102:  4096x2160   60.000 Hz 256:135 135.000 kHz  594.000 MHz
    VIC 101:  4096x2160   50.000 Hz 256:135 112.500 kHz  594.000 MHz
    VIC   5:  1920x1080i  60.000 Hz  16:9    33.750 kHz   74.250 MHz
    VIC  20:  1920x1080i  50.000 Hz  16:9    28.125 kHz   74.250 MHz
    VIC  32:  1920x1080   24.000 Hz  16:9    27.000 kHz   74.250 MHz
    VIC  33:  1920x1080   25.000 Hz  16:9    28.125 kHz   74.250 MHz
    VIC  34:  1920x1080   30.000 Hz  16:9    33.750 kHz   74.250 MHz
    VIC   4:  1280x720    60.000 Hz  16:9    45.000 kHz   74.250 MHz
    VIC  19:  1280x720    50.000 Hz  16:9    37.500 kHz   74.250 MHz
    VIC   3:   720x480    59.940 Hz  16:9    31.469 kHz   27.000 MHz
    VIC  18:   720x576    50.000 Hz  16:9    31.250 kHz   27.000 MHz
    VIC   7:  1440x480i   59.940 Hz  16:9    15.734 kHz   27.000 MHz
    VIC  22:  1440x576i   50.000 Hz  16:9    15.625 kHz   27.000 MHz
    VIC  93:  3840x2160   24.000 Hz  16:9    54.000 kHz  297.000 MHz
    VIC  94:  3840x2160   25.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz  297.000 MHz
    VIC  95:  3840x2160   30.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz  297.000 MHz
    VIC  98:  4096x2160   24.000 Hz 256:135  54.000 kHz  297.000 MHz
    VIC  99:  4096x2160   25.000 Hz 256:135  56.250 kHz  297.000 MHz
    VIC 100:  4096x2160   30.000 Hz 256:135  67.500 kHz  297.000 MHz
  Audio Data Block:
    Linear PCM:
      Max channels: 6
      Supported sample rates (kHz): 48 44.1 32
      Supported sample sizes (bits): 16
    AC-3:
      Max channels: 6
      Supported sample rates (kHz): 48 44.1 32
      Maximum bit rate: 640 kb/s
    Enhanced AC-3 (DD+):
      Max channels: 8
      Supported sample rates (kHz): 48 44.1 32
      Supports Joint Object Coding
    MAT (MLP):
      Max channels: 8
      Supported sample rates (kHz): 48
      Supports Dolby TrueHD, object audio PCM and channel-based PCM
      Hash calculation not required for object audio PCM or channel-based PCM
  Speaker Allocation Data Block:
    FL/FR - Front Left/Right
    LFE1 - Low Frequency Effects 1
    FC - Front Center
    BL/BR - Back Left/Right
  Vendor-Specific Data Block (HDMI), OUI 00-0C-03:
    Source physical address: 1.0.0.0
    DC_36bit
    DC_30bit
    DC_Y444
    Maximum TMDS clock: 300 MHz
    Supported Content Types:
      Graphics
      Photo
      Cinema
      Game
    Extended HDMI video details:
      Base EDID image size is aspect ratio
      HDMI VICs:
        HDMI VIC 1:  3840x2160   30.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz  297.000 MHz
        HDMI VIC 2:  3840x2160   25.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz  297.000 MHz
        HDMI VIC 3:  3840x2160   24.000 Hz  16:9    54.000 kHz  297.000 MHz
        HDMI VIC 4:  4096x2160   24.000 Hz 256:135  54.000 kHz  297.000 MHz
  Vendor-Specific Data Block (HDMI Forum), OUI C4-5D-D8:
    Version: 1
    Maximum TMDS Character Rate: 600 MHz
    SCDC Present
    Supports 12-bits/component Deep Color 4:2:0 Pixel Encoding
    Supports 10-bits/component Deep Color 4:2:0 Pixel Encoding
    Supports Auto Low-Latency Mode
  Video Capability Data Block:
    YCbCr quantization: No Data
    RGB quantization: Selectable (via AVI Q)
    PT scan behavior: No Data
    IT scan behavior: Always Underscanned
    CE scan behavior: Supports both over- and underscan
  Colorimetry Data Block:
    xvYCC601
    xvYCC709
    sYCC601
    opYCC601
    opRGB
    BT2020cYCC
    BT2020YCC
    BT2020RGB
  YCbCr 4:2:0 Capability Map Data Block:
    VIC  97:  3840x2160   60.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz  297.000 MHz
    VIC  96:  3840x2160   50.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz  297.000 MHz
    VIC 102:  4096x2160   60.000 Hz 256:135  67.500 kHz  297.000 MHz
    VIC 101:  4096x2160   50.000 Hz 256:135  56.250 kHz  297.000 MHz
  HDR Static Metadata Data Block:
    Electro optical transfer functions:
      Traditional gamma - SDR luminance range
      Traditional gamma - HDR luminance range
      SMPTE ST2084
      Hybrid Log-Gamma
    Supported static metadata descriptors:
      Static metadata type 1
  Vendor-Specific Video Data Block (HDR10+), OUI 90-84-8B:
    Application Version: 1
  Vendor-Specific Video Data Block (Dolby), OUI 00-D0-46:
    Version: 2 (12 bytes)
    DM Version: 3.x
    Backlt Min Luma: 100 cd/m^2
    Interface: Low-Latency
    Supports 10b 12b 444: Not supported
    Target Min PQ v2: 280
    Target Max PQ v2: 2770
    Unique Rx, Ry: 0.66796875, 0.30859375
    Unique Gx, Gy: 0.26171875, 0.63281250
    Unique Bx, By: 0.15234375, 0.05468750
  Vendor-Specific Audio Data Block (Dolby), OUI 00-D0-46:
    Version: 1 (7 bytes)
    Height speaker zone present
    Surround speaker zone present
    Center speaker zone present
  Detailed Timing Descriptors:
    DTD 3:  1366x768    59.790 Hz 683:384  47.712 kHz   85.500 MHz (698 mm x 392 mm)
                 Hfront   70 Hsync 143 Hback 213 Hpol P
                 Vfront    3 Vsync   3 Vback  24 Vpol P
Checksum: 0xbc
```

Yes, it does support HDR10+ and Dolby Vision. No, it does not support 30 fps 4:2:0, it does support 60 fps though.

```
YCbCr 4:2:0 Capability Map Data Block:
    VIC  97:  3840x2160   60.000 Hz  16:9    67.500 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC  96:  3840x2160   50.000 Hz  16:9    56.250 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC 102:  4096x2160   60.000 Hz 256:135  67.500 kHz 297.000 MHz
    VIC 101:  4096x2160   50.000 Hz 256:135  56.250 kHz 297.000 MHz
```

For 12 bit 4:2:0 you should check yourself.

Those videos are HDR (smpte2084).